# Possible to create a WCF service on a Windows Phone 7 device?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I would like to find some way for the Windows Phone 7 to be the WCF server/service side so my Windows desktop application can initiate a WCF session to the phone device. Or someway to effectively listen on a socket I could tickle to have the phone initiate the WCF session to the desktop. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No socket support, and no way to get the phone to listen on a port.

You would need to fake it, perhaps by creating a messaging service that both can talk to.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I found a couple mentions of possibly adding socket support but I wonder if even then they will allow listen. Thanks!

Comment: I think if you can find the right people to ask, you would be able to get socket support as a technical exception using a native library. The same way some carrier apps get access to APIs not in the official API. But my guess is that unless you are Skype, they are probably too busy to work with you on this at the moment.